# XMLHttpRequest not working. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, xmldocument

If you head over to [flowbase.co.uk](http://www.flowbase.co.uk) and view the source, you'll see what I mean. The text, when clicked, fires a function in an external js file (scripty.js). This then should retrieve the contents of an XML file on the same server and parse those contents into an XML document before displaying the length of the variable holding this XML document. For some reason, i'm not getting any joy - nothing at all happens when clicking the text.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the javascript console for errors.

Comment: Use [tutorials](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/ajax.shtml) to figure out what you're supposed to do!

Comment: Vivek - that is a reference not a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`responseXML` is not a function, it is a variable.

Change

```
dataModel = requestData.responseXML();
```

To

```
dataModel = requestData.responseXML;
```

Comment: Thanks! Silly error on my part! responseXML is of course a property of the XMLHttpRequest object. :)

Comment: I am glad you got it to work :)